# ListEmptyComponent not taking full screen with flex 1 in React Native Section List

Tags: react-native, flexbox

So I am using React Native Section List and following is my Code of ListEmptyContent

```
// define your styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    width: 140,
    height: 120,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#363a45',
  },
  subTitleStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#898d97',
  },
});
// create a component
const GPEmtptyTransaction = ({ firstLine, secondLine }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={images.emptyTransactionIcon} style={styles.imageStyle} />
      <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{firstLine}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.subTitleStyle}>{secondLine}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

But when EmptyTemplate is rendered it is rendered on Top and not stretching to full screen.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @splash I was able to solve it using FlexBox. So I added SectionList in a View with flex 1 and it was all sorted out.

Comment: I use it in flatlist . https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17944#issuecomment-382763099

Answer (score 28):

This works for me, apply `flexGrow: 1` to `contentContainerStyle`

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.operations}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyPlaceHolder />}
    renderItem={this.renderOperationItem} />
```

Answer (score 4):

For me what worked was adding some styles to the contentContainerStyle as well:

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}
```

The SectionList complete setup on my end was:

```
<SectionList
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    sections={filteredData}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    initialNumToRender={15}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}
    ListEmptyComponent={() => (
        <EmptyListComponent
            icon={<Document />}
            message={'Your roster is empty'}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}`  prop to `FlatList`

Answer (score -2):

I got success with the simple trick as below

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
```

than I declare the empty component

```
_listEmptyComponent = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          height: SCREEN_HEIGHT , //responsible for 100% height
          backgroundColor: "#ddd"
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            fontSize: 20
          }}
        >
          No Contracts Found
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
```

And at last `Flatlist` look like :

```
          <FlatList
            extraData={this.props.contracts}
            data={this.props.contracts}
            ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent.bind(this)}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.contractName}>
              <Text/>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          />
```

Comment: This solution is not ideal because it will make empty list component stretch to full height of device without considering top/bottom headers or footers or any other space.